# Did humans and Jawas ever live together?

Tags: star-wars

When I say live together, I am not referring to humans coexisting in the same area or much less mating with Jawas but living close together as in a family, sharing shelter, food and working together like humans and ewoks in *Return of the Jedi* and Boba Fett and tusken raiders in *The Book of Boba Fett*.

I remember seeing in *Star Wars: A New Hope*, during the scene where Uncle Owen and Luke are purchasing captured droids from the Jawas, a human (regarded as a goof) working on the droids with the Jawas; and more recently, during the episode "The Return of the Mandalorian" of *The Book of Boba Fett*, human Peli Motto not only speaks Jawaese and trade talk with Jawas but she also says that she was dating one of them.

Wookieepedia classifies Jawas as sentient and humanoids, and the original Star Wars novelization compares Jawas to devolved humans. The Mystery of the Rebellious Robot calls them the "subhuman inhabitants of Tatooine" and Star Wars: Knights of the Old Republic puts forth the theory that perhaps the Jawas are, in fact, Humans.

With that being said, I ask if there is any evidence of humans and Jawas living together in the Star Wars Universe.

[image: Star Wars A New Hope still image]

Comment: "Droid sacrifice; humans and Jawas, living together; mass hysteria!"

Comment: @DavidW Aw, you beat me to the joke!

Comment: “Coming this fall on Disney Plus, the small comedy with a big heart that knows one man’s desert trash is another man’s treasure: _Bless This Sandcrawler!_”

Comment: I legit want a side story about the Jawa crew of a sandcrawler roaming Tattooine, scavenging, and fending off Tuskens (and the occasional loon with a shiny helmet).

Comment: @Ringo Mehndra  The phrase "...and the original Star Wars novelization compares Jawas as devolved humans."  should be rewritten to say either "...and the original Star Wars novelization compares Jawas TO devolved humans." or "...and the original Star Wars novelization DESCRIBES Jawas as devolved humans." depending on which is correct.  It is ungrammatical to say something is compared as somesthing.

Comment: @M.A.Golding - Fixed. Thanks

Comment: Also, they're furry. Very furry.

Answer (score 5):

In the Obi-Wan Kenobi show recently released by Disney, we meet a friend of Obi-Wan's, Teeka the Jawa (though maybe not a friend, as evidenced by his theft of parts from Kenobi), and we see that, they are brought together by a mutually beneficial relationship: Teeka gets the parts that Obi-Wan needs (and occasionally makes more needs to fill), and Obi-Wan pays Teeka. So while there is not evidence of anything like an adoptive family relationship, it is clear that there are personal relationships that seem fairly close between the two species.

We see a similar relationship between Peli Motto and a group of Jawas in both The Book of Boba Fett and The Mandalorian where they supply her with parts and, by stripping parts from nearby vehicles, business.

Comment: Sounds like business partners; almost.

Comment: @Clockwork, basically yes.